# How can I iterate in reverse over a map in C++?

Tags: c++, loops, dictionary, for-loop, containers

I'm having trouble iterating in reverse over a map in GCC C++. When I use a reverse iterator, it seems I can't assign anything to it - the compiler complains. I'm working around it with some awkward code using a forward iterator, but it's not very elegant. Any thoughts?

Comment: What you haven't told us is what you want to do.

Comment: Sounds like you might be using a reverse iterator, but still calling begin and end rather than rbegin and rend. GMan's solution might be what you're looking for. But posting some code will help us help you.

Comment: You should check, how you obtain iterator range ( it should be rbegin()/rend() instead begin()/end() ). Do you really use reverse_iterator ( not const_reverse_iterator )?

Comment: Thanks - I thought I had tried the rbegin/rend, but must have got myself tangled up somehow.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Here's an example of iterating backward through a `std::map`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m;
    m["a"] = "1";
    m["b"] = "2";
    m["c"] = "3";

    for (auto iter = m.rbegin(); iter != m.rend(); ++iter) {
        std::cout << iter->first << ": " << iter->second << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If you are pre-C++11, you'll just need to spell out `auto`, which is:

```
std::map<std::string, std::string>::reverse_iterator
```

Note that if you're using boost, you can use a range-based for loop with a reverse adapter:

```
#include <boost/range/adaptor/reversed.hpp>

for (auto& iter : boost::adaptors::reverse(m)) {
    std::cout << iter.first << ": " << iter.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to use `auto` here?

Comment: @Wildling: Yeah, this answer was posted before C++11.

Comment: Just in case if you are wondering how to work without auto iter, define:  std::map<std::string, std::string>::reverse_iterator instead of regular iterator. Took me a while to google out as compiler issue is not most helpful.

Answer (score 13):

Since [C++20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B20) you can make use of the range adaptor [`std::views::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/reverse_view) from the [Ranges library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges). If you add this to a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) with [structured binding](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding), iterating backwards over an `std::map` could be done as follows:

```
#include <map>
#include <ranges>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, int> m = { {"a", 1}, {"b", 2}, {"c", 3} };

    for (auto const& [k, v] : m | std::views::reverse)
        std::cout << k << " => " << v << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> c => 3
> b => 2
> a => 1

[Code on Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uD41hqXcttIfAucN)